# python raw_input not prompting for user input in a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, counter

I'm using the Python 2.7.15 version to write a while loop which will keep adding queries against till the number of queries match the counter. The issue that I am running into is that the QUERY variable is not prompting me for any input. Any help is appreciated. The code is below:

```
QUERIES = []
NUMBER_OF_QUERIES = int(input('Number of queries being used: '))
COUNTER = 0
while NUMBER_OF_QUERIES < COUNTER:
    QUERY = raw_input('Input required query:')
    QUERIES.append(QUERY)
    COUNTER = COUNTER + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while NUMBER_OF_QUERIES < COUNTER:
```

`COUNTER` is zero, so unless the user entered a negative number, this expression is false, so the input never happens.

Perhaps you meant to write `> COUNTER` instead?

Comment: I think an easier way would be `while COUNTER < NUMBER_OF_QUERIES`. Mentally at least.

Comment: As a side note you are using `input` and `raw_input` which are slightly different